# How to cast an ActiveRecord object to another class when using STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, casting, single-table-inheritance

I'm currently using ActiveRecord single table inheritance.

How can I cast one of my models from type A to B? They have the same parent.

Comment: There should be no need to cast.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`#becomes` is what you are looking for:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes

Comment: It looks like becomes is now deprecated. Do you know if there is a method that can take its place - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/becomes

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes not deprecated, just moved.

Comment: This is not casting.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, casting is the wrong word for use here, it achieves what this person wants.

Comment: @schmijos, independently of how data is persisted, how is "converting one data type into another" not casting? omar, why is the word wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to cast since Ruby does not perform any type-checking at compile time. What are you trying to accomplish?

Say you have a class `Dad`, and child classes `Son` and `Daughter`.

You could just have a variable @dad and store in it either a `Son` or `Daughter` object, and just treat it as if it were a `Dad`. As long as they respond to the same methods, it makes no difference. This is a concept called "duck typing".

Comment: I don't exactly remember why I did this question, but if I remember well it is needed when you have a STI relationship with a polymorphic association, or else it is saved with the wrong `type` field.

Comment: Ruby does not, however, Rails does https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1d08b98055508d00844cd30cbb68a4afa38a77a1/activerecord/lib/active_record/errors.rb#L14

Comment: Sometimes (usually) the child classes have more methods than the parent class, so if you need to access one of those methods, you have to cast it to the appropriate class.

Answer (score 3):

If we have something like following

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
end

Class B < A
end
```

we can use becomes

```
a = A.first
b = a.becomes(B)
```

or vice versa

Answer (score -2):

Create a new instance of B to setting the values for attributes it shares with A.

Something like:

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class A < C
end

class B < C
end

@a = A.new(...)
@b = B.new(@a.attr1, @a.attr2, ..., @a.attrN)
```

Comment: This is not casting... is it?

Comment: @Webbisshh No, it's not. This is an approximation for the particular problem posed in the question.

Comment: `becomes` is implemented like this except that it copies more than just the attributes.  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes and view the source code.

Comment: but it doesnt copy relations.. like user.post_ids

Comment: It's inheritance, it's not casting - the casting would allow to turn the object of class B to class A.